# Load csv to list but skip line feed

Tags: python, list, csv

Trying to load a csv into a database.

```
def csvtolist(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return list(map(tuple,reader))

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    params =csvtolist(os.path.join(os.fsdecode(directory), filename))
    print(params)         
    cursor.executemany("INSERT into PRODUCTSTRUCTURE values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",params)
```

I get and error because the sequence contains the line feed:

```
    cursor.executemany("INSERT into PRODUCTSTRUCTURE values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 8 parameter markers, but 9 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Example of sequence from `print(params)` with the unwanted 9th `\n`:

`('MilhoSP', 'BR001', '', '', '', '', '', '', '\n')`

Comment: it seems that your csv file last field contains a newline. Anyway you only need 8 parameters, so you could just remove it

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT into PRODUCTSTRUCTURE values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",params[:-1])
```

The `params[:-1]` would get you everything except the last one, in your case the the 9th one.

**Alternate:**

Based on the helpful comment, using `params[0:8]` will always give you 8 elements. This is future proof even when the CSV file changes the number of columns.

Comment: actually you have to do `params[:8]` because you need 8 values. If there are exactly 8 values in one row for some reason, your slicing destroys a valid line (just a suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this before you pass the parameters to your SQL statement:

```
params = tuple(x for x in params if x != '\n')
```